# level of spatial aggregation of polygons

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, polygon, r, aggregation

I am looking for a method that allows me to obtain the spatial aggregation of polygons for each cell of a grid with 10kmx10km resolution.

In each cell (10kmx10km), I want to be able to consider that big polygons that share a line segment as well as big polygons within certain distances (e.g., 1km), represent areas with high aggregation. Smaller polygons with the same spatial distribution represent a medium aggregation cell. While small disperse polygons represent areas with low aggregation.

What is the best way to do this (in ArcGIS, QGIS or R)?

Comment: It is unclear what you want to calculate nor what your inputs are. Could you please provide quantitative descriptions of these?